# Implement 'Do this if object doesn't exist' in conversion from Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

I am converting some code to Swift and I have encountered a problem that seems related to unwrapping an optional so I can implement the pattern:

If object exists, use it. If not create it.

I also wonder about my use of NSPredicate.

here is the Obj-C code that works:

```
UILabel *label = [[[cell.contentView subviews] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UIView *subview, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]);
}]] firstObject];

if (!label) {
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
}
```

Here is my revised code in Swift:

```
    let subViews = cell.contentView.subviews
    let labelPredicate = NSPredicate { (UIView subview, _) -> Bool in
        return subview.isKindOfClass(UILabel) }

    let labels = (subViews as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(labelPredicate) as! [UILabel]
    let label = labels[0]

    if (!label) {
        label = UILabel(frame: view.bounds)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize( 10)
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

    }
```

The problem occurs on the if(!label) line with an xcode error of "Could not find an overload for '!' that accepts the supplied arguments."

How do I properly test if label exists?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't put the if test clause in parenthesis, and try `if label != nil`. See what it says then.

Comment: @user2194039 It changes the error message to "Binary operator != cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel' and 'nil'

Comment: @user2194039 you can only compare with `nil` if the type is an optional

Comment: tangobango, by the way, is this snippet from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `cellForItemAtIndexPath`? If so, there might be better patterns that would would streamline this further...

Comment: @DanZimm Yeah, thanks, I know. I asked only because I thought if the OP'er tried it out, getting past the syntax error might be enough to help them figure it out. In any case, I submitted an answer trying to explain that.

Comment: @Rob it's in a colectionView(cellForItemAtIndexPath:)

Comment: @tangobango We generally would not iterate through the cell looking for labels, but would rather define a cell subclass with a weak reference to the outlet, which we'd ideally have the storyboard or nib hook up automatically, or if you're determined to do it programmatically, do it in the `init` method (`initWithCoder`, IIRC). Google "uicollectionviewcell subclass example" or "uicollectionviewcell subclass tutorial" for examples of better patterns.

Comment: @Rob. Great advice about using a subclass and the storyboard. I am trying to update someone else's code that uses a third-party library and I thought I'd start with as direct a translation as I could.  Anyway, I will do as you suggest straightaway as it may eliminate some other headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in your original question, you have committed a syntax error in Swift. Conditional clauses do not go in parenthesis.

As written in our comments, Swift is complaining because it cannot compare a UILabel to nil with a `!=` operator.

When you used `as! [UILabel]` after filtering your array, you guaranteed to Swift that the `labels` array would contain UILabels. Then in your next line, you assigned `labels[0]` to `label`. By asking for the member at index 0, you guaranteed to Swift that there would indeed be a member at index 0. So finally, when you tried to check if `label` was nil, Swift is saying "it cannot be, because you told me so." It knows `label` cannot be nil, and refuses to compare.

There are many ways you can improve this, but the easiest would be to change:

```
let labels = // ...
let label = labels[0]
if label == nil {
    // ...
}
```

to

```
let labels = // ...
let label: UILabel                // Declare label, but do not assign in yet

if let lbl = labels.first {
    label = lbl                   // Assign the UILabel in index 0
} else {
    label = UILabel(frame: view.bounds)    // Create a new UILabel
    // ...
}

// Do whatever with label
```

In this example, we declare that `label` will be a UILabel, but do not assign anything to it yet. We declare it outside the scope of the `if let / else` so that it will be available afterward. Swift will not let us do anything until we assign to it, but that's okay.

Next we check if there is a label in `labels` index 0. If so, assign it to `label`. If not, we'll create a new label and set it up.

After we assign a UILabel to label, you're free to continue as planned.

---

I highly suggest reading up on [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) and [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245), because they are at the heart of Swift, and make a huge difference in how you structure your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. I'm still having a problem, because I can do 'if let label = label.first' and then do something, but I need to do something 'if label = label.first' fails.. Either way, then I need to manipulate 'label' further. I tried an 'else' but then, in either condition, I can't manipulate 'label'. I get 'unresolved identifier.' Sorry for being so dense.

Comment: @tangobango I've updated my answer with a solution for you. And I also highly recommend you follow Rob's advice about using `.filter` instead of `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Thanks. That sorts it and makes perfect sense, now that I see it. I will follow Rob's advice, as well.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The title of the question is how to use predicates in Swift. Frankly, I would consider using `filter` method, which eliminates the `NSPredicate` altogether:

   ```
   let labels = subViews.filter { $0 is UILabel }
   ```
2. And even if you wanted to use `NSPredicate`, I might suggest simplifying the syntax:

   ```
   let labelPredicate = NSPredicate { (subview, _) -> Bool in subview is UILabel }
   ```
3. Regarding the `if (!label)` syntax, the equivalent Swift syntax would be

   ```
   if label == nil { ... }
   ```

   You cannot use `!` operator with any random type in Swift. Explicitly test to see if the optional is `nil` or not.
4. By the way, the process of building an array of labels in order to see if there is a label is a little inefficient. You could test for the existence of a label without building array with `reduce`:

   ```
   let hasLabel = subViews.reduce(false) { alreadyFoundLabel, subview in alreadyFoundLabel || subview is UILabel }
   if !hasLabel { ... }
   ```

   Or, procedurally you could just loop through the subviews:

   ```
   var hasLabel = false
   for control in subViews {
       println(control)
       if control is UILabel {
           hasLabel = true
           break;
       }
   }
   if !hasLabel { ... }
   ```

   Clearly, if you need he array of labels for other purposes, then by all means, build it. But building an array solely for the purpose of checking for the existence of something is inefficient.

Comment: Thanks. I will clean up my method and the way I get the label once I can solve the basic problem, which I'd say is 'If a label exists, use it. If not, create one' That was my reason for trying 'if !label' or 'if label == nil' but neither works.

Comment: If `label` is optional (e.g. `let label = labels.first`), then `if label == nil { ... }` is the correct syntax.